# Hormones - biotic or abiotic

Tags: endocrinology

Are hormones biotic or abiotic? I have tried reading different articles, and  I've found that it is both, but can that be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hormones occur inside organisms as signaling factors, and arise from biological activities, the development or homeostasis of the organism.

Thus, **they are considered neither biotic nor abiotic factors in ecology.**

(Terrible analogy warning!) It's a bit like asking whether the wheel of a car is petrol- or diesel-based. It makes no sense!

Here's a helpful, comprehensive [website](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Abiotic_vs_Biotic).

Biotic (*living*) factors are living organisms in an ecosystem, that must share common resources or compete in a habitat one way or another. Abiotic (*non-living*) factors are things like temperature, wind, salinity, etc. that affect individuals or the community of an ecosystem.

As you can see, hormones are just one of many components of a living organism. They aren't living themselves. It's a silly question to ask, as I hope you can see now.